# Products not showing on a multi store view magento site

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, multicurrency

I am creating a magento site with multiple store views. I have one website and two stores. One for the UK & one for the US. Both sites were showing products but now the US site store view 2 is not showing any.

I have updated indexes a load of times, checked the flushed cache, deleted everything from var/cache folder etc. Nothing seems to bring back the products to the US site.

I have also checked that it's enabled for all websites but as i only have one it is always on.

Hopefully this is something simple.

Answer (score 0):

Go in **Catalog -> Manage Categories** switch your view to **US** and see if your products are assigned to the category that you want.
If they are not assigned, do assign them once more and then **flush cache, reindex** and see what happens.

Also You have to check product is enable or not.

Comment: I found out the issue. I had not imported the currency rates properly. As soon as i did it again all store views had products. Drove me mad for hours!

Comment: for multistore, how to create symbolic links for localhost.

Comment: @CraigShort What did you mean by 'import currency rates properly'?